# How to create a class which can only have a single instance in C#

Tags: c#, .net, singleton, design-patterns

I wonder if there is a mechanism or pattern to allow only one instance of a class in C#. I have heard of the `Singleton` class, but i don't know how to use it well.

Comment: What about if I would have _n_ instances of the class instead one? (curiosity)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using singleton, that is a class which only allows a single instance of itself to be created.

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
     public static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();
     private Singleton() {}
}
```

The operation of this pattern is simple and could be reduced to the following:

Hide the constructor of the Singleton class, so that clients may not be instantiated.
            To declare the Singleton class private member variable containing the reference to the unique instance that we handle.
            Provide in class Singleton a function or property that provides access to the one maintained by the Singleton instance.

Answer (score 8):

this can be sample Singletone implementation

```
public sealed class CSingleTone
{
    private static CSingleTone instance;
    public int SomeValue{ get; set; }
    public static CSingleTone Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new CSingleTone();
            return instance;
        }
    }
    private CSingleTone()
    {
    }
}
```

can be used in this way

```
int r = CSingleTone.Instance.SomeValue;
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to read our own Jon Skeet's [blog (Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C#)](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx).

Intent of Singletom Pattern is to "ensure a class has only one instance, and provide a global point of access to it".

Here's how you can do it.

```
public sealed class Singleton {

    private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    private Singleton() {       
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get 
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: And if I would have at most n instances of the class instead one? (curiosity)

Comment: This answer may predate newer syntax... but would `public static Singleton Instance { get; } = new Singleton();` do the trick, avoiding the `private readonly` field?

Answer (score 2):

Singleton is not a class, but rather a pattern.
Here is an example:

```
class Singleton {
    private Singleton() {}

    static private Singleton GetIt() {
        return theOne;
    }

    static private Singleton theOne = new Singleton();
}
```

Comment: Are there any issue(s) with MT caused by being non-readonly? (I do not know here.)

Comment: Not really.`theOne` is private so doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to just declare a `static` class with only `static` members. Or you can implement the Singleton pattern by giving the class a `private` constructor:

```
public class MySingleton
{
    public static readonly MySingleton Instance = new MySingleton();

    private MySingleton() { }

    // Members ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a simple example of singleton class

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    SiteStructure s = SiteStructure.Instance;
    }
}

public sealed class SiteStructure
{
    static readonly SiteStructure _instance = new SiteStructure();
    public static SiteStructure Instance
    {
    get
    {
        return _instance;
    }
    }
    SiteStructure()
    {
    // Initialize.
    }
}
```

here, Readonly allows `thread-safety`, and that means it can be only `allocated once`. It has a `public static getter`. The `Instance property` is used by callers to get the **[singleton](http://www.dotnetperls.com/singleton)** instance.
`Sealed` is known to allow the compiler to perform special optimizations during `JIT compilation`. The final methods above are the private instance constructor and an Initialize method. `Private constructors` mean the class can `only allocate itself`.